# why error is not going from R.java in android

Tags: android

```
public static final class id {
        public static int Phone Number=0x7f050043;

error shows in a above link Phone Number=0x7f050043.
```

What could be the problem? I have already changed the XML id from `@+id/Phone Number` to `@+id/phoneNumber`.

I've done many things related with this like clean the project, delete gen folder, but the error persists. My project submission is tomorrow. Please help me find a Solution.

my XML file is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.pgfinder.Add_PG" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="470dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/gender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/house"
            android:layout_below="@+id/house"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Pg For Male or Female" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/landmark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/city"
            android:layout_below="@+id/city"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Landmark" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phone_number"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:hint="Phone Number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/landmark"
            android:layout_below="@+id/landmark"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/house"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="House Address" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/meal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gender"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gender"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Pg With Meal or Not" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/meal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/meal"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="City" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_pg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Phone Number"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Phone Number"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="Add New PG" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/add_pg"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/add_pg"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Phone Number"
            android:text="Cancel" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your full xml layout file.

Comment: please post your import section....... i need to know which R is imported ..

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Delete **build** folder from project, and recompile your code. Recompilation will recreate build folder (and R file). It will solve the issue.

Step 2: If above step doesn't work rename id i.e. `@+id/phoneNumber` to `@+id/phoneNumber1` and perform step 1 again.

**Update**

Replace each instance of **Phone Number** with **phone_number** like in 
`android:layout_below="@+id/Phone Number"` or `android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Phone Number"`. Do it in both buttons i.e. `add_pg` and `back`.

See:

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_pg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Phone Number"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Phone Number"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="Add New PG" />
```

Replace it with :

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_pg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/phone_number"
            android:layout_below="@+id/phone_number"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="Add New PG" />
```

Answer (score 0):

rename into 
@+id/phoneNumber
save Ctrl s

try manual allocating by yourself in R.java
public static int phoneNumber=0x7f050050;
save ctrl s

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happen to me , and i passed a day to fix this. really this is a stupid error. i am just shearing my experience, may be it would helpful to you . First look carefully when you type this setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do_list); hear your starting point R.l then eclipse should open a suggestion for you look like this
[image]

you import the second one not layout-android.R . the second one is created in your project hear com.example.gridtest is the project package name . then focus your imported section in your code
[image]

ok look this `import com.example.gridtest.R;` its important . If you already import this `android.R` then remove it. Thank you hope it works . ( you don't need to do this always but if you face this kinda problem then do this )
There are more option you can try this [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error/22141421#22141421)